# From where i can enter in brand carousel settings in electro theme?

Tags: themes, carousel, settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwoVE.png)

i want to remove these carousel of brand name which is content electro theme place holder. in the documentation , here is brand carousel setting is given but in my case i didnt found it, please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Product-> Attributes-> you will find brands attributes, click on it then you can change the brand with picture
Please see the video for details
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPPFED_p2to

Answer (score 0):

Go to Desktop > Electro > Footer > Brands Carousel and disable it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).